# URLs rendered with random text

Tags: asp.net, web-services

ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms app.

User logs in and normally link URLs look like this:
https://domain.com/directory/Page.aspx

On occassion ALL links for the user will be rendered with a whole bunch of extra text in the form:
https://domain.com/(F(194_random_characters_Here)/Services/directory/page.aspx

Odd thing is, the links still work.  Once it starts happening for a given user, nothing short of an app pool recycle will fix it, and even then sometimes the user also has to clear their browser cache before the extra text goes away.  We've seen it occur in several versions each of Firefox, Chrome and IE.

It's almost like the ~ portion of paths/links are getting the extra text added to them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have cookieless sessions enabled.

Look in your web.config or IIS configuration for disabling cookieless sessions.

Comment: web.config has <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="3000" />

Comment: @chrismat There might be a runtime change to configuration. Look inside your Global.asax.cs file, for example.

Comment: this doesn't happen to every user; I'm not even sure if the same user has the issue every visit.  Is it possible some third party browser plugin may be fouling things up?